# Django Formulário - Status

Tags: python-3.x, django, biblioteca, django-templates

Estou trabalhando em um sistema de administração de bibliotecas e neste momento estou criando a parte lógica para realizar um empréstimo. Eis minha grande dúvida;
Como setar um estado para livro disponível ou indisponível dentro de um formulário de maneira que esse estado seja exibido dentro de um campo de formulário readonly?

Explicando melhor: ao buscar o livro usando um código único, todas as informações do livro serão exibidas dentro de um formulário apenas de leitura, nesse formulário tem um campo para DISPONIBILIDADE que mostra se o livro está ou não disponível. Existe algum método específico pra fazer esse tipo de exibição?

Answer (score 0):

Você vai definir o atributo disable como true

> O argumento booleano desabilitado, quando definido como True, desabilita um campo de formulário usando o atributo HTML desabilitado, para que não seja editável pelos usuários. Mesmo que um usuário adultere o valor do campo enviado ao servidor, ele será ignorado em favor do valor dos dados iniciais do formulário.

```
class ItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ItemForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['my_field'].disable = True
```